# Como criar uma variável fator a partir de outros fatores?

Tags: banco-de-dados, r

Gostaria de criar uma variável nominal `X` (fator) no meu `data.frame` a partir de outras duas variáveis nominais já existentes `Renda` e `Escolaridade`:

```
Renda    Escolaridade    X 
baixa    fund. incomp    Sim
inter    superior        Nao
alta     pos grad        Nao
alta     medio           Nao
```

Assim, quando `Renda = "baixa"` e `Escolaridade = "fund. incomp"` a var. `X` receberá o `label= "Sim"` e todas as demais combinações receberão  `label="Nao"`

Tentei utilizar a função `ifelse`, mas me parece que se aplica a `var. numeric` apenas.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depois de criar a variável X, utilize o comando `as.factor()` nessa variável.

```
df <- data.frame(
   Renda = c("baixa","inter","alta","alta"),
   Escolaridade = c("fund. incomp","superior","pos grad","medio"))
df$X <- ifelse((df$Renda == "baixa" & df$Escolaridade == "fund. incomp"),"Sim","Não")
df$X <- as.factor(df$X)
```

Comment: Obrigada, Rafael. Estava dando errado, pq eu inseri apenas um = ao invés de ==

Comment: no R um = é o mesmo que <- para o teste de igualdade, tem que usar ==